# Need to take screenshot of YouTube video programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, screenshot

I need to programmatically take an image of an embedded video from various sources (not just YouTube).
So if you go to [this](https://www.youtube.com/embed/_Lc3GJ2O5ic) embedded video.

I need to take a picture of the embedded video before it starts, which in the aforementioned link is the two GT-R cars lined up.

```
string source = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/_Lc3GJ2O5ic"; 

System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser wb = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser(); 

wb.AllowNavigation = true; wb.Navigate(source);

wb.Navigate(source);

b.DocumentCompleted += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);

private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser wb = sender as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser;
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(640, 480);
            wb.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, wb.Width, wb.Height));
            wb.Dispose();

            string filepath = "C:\\Users\\myUserName\\Desktop\New folder\\gtr.bmp";
            bitmap.Save(filepath);

        }
```

but when I go to the picture all I'm getting is a blackbox:

[image]

Comment: Did you try setting `wb.Size` before navigating?

Comment: Also, just as a random guess, you might have to set user agents and some other properties as youtube may be blocking you or restricting the video playback

Comment: @Mark playback is working. I just need the image of the embed video before it starts playing.

Comment: its because the video is playing on the video card, bypassing the gdi layer.

Answer (score 0):

i'm sorry to inform you.. but maybe you are using a WRONG attitude for this one

follow these steps:

1. open chrome browser
2. enable dev tools (F12)
3. load the givven url
4. observe the network traffic

you will see that the preview for that video is already a "webp" image ready to use....

[image]

i think is is WAY better to just download the preview image instead of trying to play the video and make a screenshot.... what am i missing?

### **UPDATE**

for each video - all you need to do is just download the file (programmatically). **for instance**: the attached video has the preview image located here https://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/_Lc3GJ2O5ic/maxresdefault.webp

the inspection made by chrome clarify how can i repeat the process for different providers to better understand what i am doing as a developer

Comment: I should have clarified that I need to accomplish this programmatically, not manually. Additionally I need to support multiple embed video sources not just YouTube.

Comment: i clarify myself in the UPDATE section..enjoy :)